# Stop after first match

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to split services' name and their status with Regex.

This works fine:

```
message = "svnserve is stopped"
match = re.search(r"(.*)\s+is\s+(\w*)", message)
print match.group(1),match.group(2)
# output=> svnserve stopped
```

but when I found line like this it doesn't work:

```
message = "openssh-daemon (pid  1982) is running"
match = re.search(r"(.*)\s+is\s+(\w*)", message)
print match.group(1),match.group(2)
# output => openssh-daemon (pid  1982) running
```

How I can remove the `(pid 1982)`; I just want the name and the state.

Any help?

Comment: Note that I changed your variable name from `str` to `message`.  You should never make a user-defined name the same as one of the built-ins.  Doing so overshadows the built-in name and makes it unusable in the current scope.

Comment: I changed it right now :)  but in my code of course it's not like now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
re.search(r"(.*)\s+is\s+(\w*)",str)
```

This regex takes anything up to the first space as its first group, then matches the word "is" with an unspecified number of spaces on either side, then takes an alpha numeric character string after that as its next group. This second group includes spaces. A better strategy would be to take the first and last word, separated by spaces. Try

```
 match = re.search(r"^([\S]+).*\s([\S]+)$",str)
```

Answer (score 1):

The service name will always be the first word in the string and its state will always be the last.  So, you can simply split the string and grab these two items directly:

```
message = "svnserve is stopped"
match = message.split()
print match[0], match[-1]
```

Demo:

```
>>> message = "svnserve is stopped"
>>> match = message.split()
>>> print match[0], match[-1]
svnserve stopped
>>>
>>> message = "openssh-daemon (pid  1982) is running"
>>> match = message.split()
>>> print match[0], match[-1]
openssh-daemon running
>>>
```

Comment: thanks, but I need to use regex because I grap the services from different OS, so I just want  to change the pattern and index.

Comment: Well, in that case you could use a pattern such as: `r"(.*?)\s.*?is\s(\w*)"`.  The important part is the `?` characters, which make the matching non-greedy (they match as little as possible).  However, I'm sure that using Regex is unnecessary since your data is very ordered.  The parts you want are always in the same place.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `re.findall` function to do a global match. `\S+` matches one or more non-space characters.

```
>>> m = re.findall(r'^\S+|\S+$', message)
>>> print(m[0],m[1])
svnserve stopped
>>> message = "openssh-daemon (pid  1982) is running"
>>> m = re.findall(r'^\S+|\S+$', message)
>>> print(m[0],m[1])
openssh-daemon running
```

OR

If you want to fed  `\s+is\s+` into your regex then try the below.

```
>>> message = "openssh-daemon (pid  1982) is running"
>>> m = re.search(r'^(\S+).*?\s+is\s+.*?(\S+)$', message)
>>> print(m.group(1),m.group(2))
openssh-daemon running
```

Or you could simply use `re.search(r'^(\S+).*?(\S+)$', message)`